# Silverlight swing effect in web template?

Tags: silverlight

Can anyone tell how this [check this link here](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/WebTemplate) (swing) effect is given in this web template of Silverlight?
Is there any open source project or template like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the Sample and take a look at the source code.

Its already covered with a Creative Commons license, take a look for any additional licence or readme just in case the author has included an attribution requirement.